# Copying contiguous & non-contiguous cells using SpecialCells in VBA

Tags: excel, vba, copy-paste

I want to filter data from a file and paste the information from the visible cells into a separate workbook.

The code works when I have multiple cells (greater than 1) filtered.
When the data filtered is a single row, and if it is contiguous cells, it is not copying the mentioned range.

Code to select the visible range to copy:

```vb
        If SATsht.AutoFilter.Range.Columns(11).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Cells.Count - 1 < 1 Then
            AdditionsCount = SATsht.AutoFilter.Range.Columns(11).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Cells.Count
            MsgBox "There are no New Additions after filtering out the Duplicate Activities"
            GoTo NextMARFilter
            'SATfile.Close False
            'Exit Sub
        End If
        AdditionsCount = SATsht.AutoFilter.Range.Columns(11).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Cells.Count - 1
        
        'Update all the fields from SATfile to MARfile

        For X = 2 To SATCols

            On Error Resume Next
            Debug.Print SATsht.Cells(2, X)
            MARheader = Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(SATsht.Cells(2, X), MARheaderRng, 0)
            If Err.Number > 0 Then GoTo NextHeader
            On Error GoTo 0
            
            SATfile.Activate
            SATsht.Range(Cells(3, X), Cells(SATRows, X)).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Select 'PROBLEM IS HERE
            Selection.Copy
            MARfile.Activate
            MARfile.Sheets(1).Cells(MARoldRows + 1, MARheader).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
            
NextHeader:
        Next
```

The line of code when I'm having issues.

```
SATsht.Range(Cells(3, X), Cells(SATRows, X)).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Select
```

The code is selecting the entire visible range available instead of the mentioned visible cell.

Before Selection (in the code):
[image]

After Selection (in the code):
[image]

Logically it has to select the first visible cell (in this case E3) below the header and it needs to be repeated for each column one after the other.

Comment: What `MARheaderRng` range does contain? Declaring `MARheader As Variant` and using `Application.Match(SATsht.Cells(2, X), MARheaderRng, 0)` will not raise a fatal error if no match exists, so you may not using `On Error Resume Next`. And checking `if not IsError(MARheader) Then`.  Then, what does `SATCols` is? Since `SATsht` **contains only one column**, what do you expect from `SATsht.Cells(2, X)`? `x` can be only 1. Am I missing anything?  Besides that, why `...Cells.Count - 1 < 1` instead of ...`Cells.Count = 0`?

Comment: ```MARHeaderRng``` is only the header range. But the problem existing is at this line of code - 
``` SATsht.Range(Cells(3, X), Cells(SATRows,X)).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Select 'PROBLEM IS HERE```

Comment: You should read a little more carefully my above comment, I think... What do you expect from `SATsht.Range(Cells(3, X), Cells(SATRows,X))`? As mentioned above, `SATsht` is a range having only one column. Then, `Cells(3, x)` refers the worksheet. `SATsht` having only one column, ou can play only with its rows cells. The column must invariable be  **1**. What do you think/need that such a construction to return?

Comment: I haven't read the question that well, but when I use filter and then loop trough the results, I use `If SATsht.Rows(x).Hidden = False Then`, otherwise I get error reading a hidden row. Hope that helps.

Comment: @Loveb It is not about identifying the hidden rows, it is about selecting the visible filtered rows (it could be 1, 2, 3, or even more. Now in this case, when I filtered, I have got only 1 row as visible data which is the 3rd row, but however, it is not selecting the visible cell as mentioned in the code instead selecting the complete sheet visible range. And it is selecting the rows accurately when there the filtered rows are more than 1. Let me know if you need any other info. :)

Comment: @FaneDuru MARHeader is the Column position where the cell needs to be pasted in MARHeaderRng and SATCols is the total columns that we have from the source file (SAT File). Each column header name is taken and searched in the Target File (MAR file) and if the column name is matching, then the same visible data is copied from SAT File and pasted into the MAR file. That is the process workaround here

Comment: You are refering to the first row "3", but if you filter the data, the first visible row could be nr 5. If row 3 is hidden, you get error.

Comment: Also I strongly recommend that you don't use copy/paste.  Use something like `For Each Rng In Range("B2:" & cells(2, SATCols).address)` and `MARfile.Sheets(1).Cells(MARoldRows + 1, MARheader) = Rng.Value`

Comment: @Loveb When we use SpecialCells, it considers only visible cells right, then I'm just mentioning the start and the end points with SpecialCells, so that only visible cells are selected

Comment: You're right. I found the reason. You have to stand in the sheet you're copying from. Change `SATfile.Activate` to `SATsht.Activate`

Comment: @Loveb I have tried activating the sheet with SATsht.Activate, but it is still selecting the entire Visible range. Actually, the original code is working when we have multiple cells visible & filtered, but it is not selecting the appropriate cells only when we have one visible row.

Comment: When I tryed the code and changed `SATfile.Activate` to `SATsht.Activate`, everything works, one row or several. What I can't see is the content of MARoldRows and MARheader, maybe the code is wrong there. You have to show more code if you want more help. Also try to avoid copy/paste, it's slow, it's more safe to write `SATsht.Range(Cells(3, X), Cells(SATRows, X)).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible) = MARsht.Cells(MARoldRows + 1, MARheader)` , then you don't need to select different sheets either.

Comment: @Loveb, Actually I have 3 options in B Column to choose, for the users, based on the selection, the code executes accordingly in the Loop. If you need, I can paste the entire code here in the comment for your reference. please let me know, thank you